# How to Debug multiple Sharepoint services on the same machine?

Tags: wcf, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I need to debug a Sharepoint WCF service that is deployed for Sharepoint 2010. However, a colleague needs to debug another Sharepoint service deployed on the same phyical machine. If we debug at the same time strange things occur with the Visual Studio debugger. For example, his debugger would break at breakpoints I have set, or I am seeing exceptions raised by his code. Mind you, we are debugging different services in different solutions. From the information I have gathered so far, this behaviour is like this because there is only one w3wp process per application pool that both the Visual Studio Debugger instances attach to.
So I figured I should try running my service in another applicaion pool to get a different w3wp.exe to attach to. Here is what I tried, but I am not sure, if what I attempted makes any sense, please clarify:

IIS Manager shows that there are two different Sharepoint application pools (excluding the one for Central Adminisitration) and a Site for each. So I tried deploying my service using the other application pool by setting the deployment location to the URL of the other site. However the virtual _vti_bin directory of the service still maps to the same physical directory `...\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\`. Deploying from Visual Studio works, but getting a ServiceReference does not. Trying to open `<url>/_vti_bin/MyService.svc/MEX` shows an error page telling me that therer is already a binding instance associated to the URL. So, I guess this is either not the way to do this, or it is simply not possible to "isolate" services in this way. I am very hesitant to just trial-and-error with IIS Manager or Sharepoint Central Administration settings, because I feel I don't know enough to avoid screwing things up.

Could someone tell me how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you specify when deploying in Visual Studio can be misleading. If you have a sandboxed solution, it gets deployed to this location. If you have a farm solution, it gets deployed centrally and it uses the URL to figure out what application pool to recycle. If you have web application specific settings in the solution i.e. safecontrols), these will be applied to the web application hosting the URL.

The _vti_bin is available to every site in the whole farm; as is _layouts. Since a service will be exposed through multiple URL's (one for each site) the SharePoint team has created custom factory classes to make this possible. Check out one of the built in svc files, and you will see that it uses a special factory class. Use this in your svc file to expose your service in all sites.

As for the debugging, it's never a good idea to have multiple developers using the same machine. If you really want to do it, I suggest using two web applications with different application pools. That way each developer has their own process to attach to. If you use different accounts for the application pool, it makes it easier to find the correct one in the 'attach process' dialog.

Comment: I know that debugging on the same machine is not optimal, but at the moment we only have one machine available that is set up to host Sharepoint. Both our solutions are farm solutions btw. I double checked that we are debugging on different application pools and that the debuggers really attach to different w3wp.exe processes. When re-deploying the services the correct application pools are recycled as well, yet the problem still remains.